# How to assign the value of field 'NewValue' of CaseHistory object to a text field in Apex class?

Tags: apex

I want to assign the value of Standard field **'NewValue'** of the object **'CaseHistory'** to a **TEXT** type field of another custom object. **Is it possible ?** The datatype of **'NewValue'** field is **'anyType'** as per the below link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casehistory.htm.

And if I try to assign the **'NewValue'** field value to any other **TEXT** type custom field like **(CSHU.New_Status_Value__c = CH.NewValue;)** then it throws me error saying:

**Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Object to String**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states the datatype of the NewValue field on a Case History is an Object .You may typecast into a String like below

```
CSHU.New_Status_Value__c = (string)CH.NewValue;
```